# Having trouble with the very last part of my python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

All of the code here works for the problem I was given I just need to make the last line look like this:

```
The highest rain total was Thursday with 6.54
```

Instead of:

```
Highest value is:  6.54
```

I realize its an easy thing to do but id appreciate some help if anyone could assist me real quick. Thanks in advance

```
Sunday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Sunday: "))
Monday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Monday: "))
Tuesday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Tuesday: "))
Wednesday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Wednsday: "))
Thursday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Thursday: "))
Friday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Friday: "))
Saturday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Saturday: "))

weekdays = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]

print("Highest value is: ", max(weekdays))

index = 0
```

Comment: Use a dictionary that maps day names to their totals, rather than separate variables. Then you can find the dictionary key with the maximum total.

Comment: Or a list of tuples of the form `(dayname, raintotal)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, it would be easier if you changed your data structure and using a `dict` instead of a `list`, whose keys would be the days' names and values the one you provide. Then, you can find the max value and print it along with the name of the day:

```
weekdays = {'Sunday' : Sunday, 'Monday' : Monday, 'Tuesday' : Tuesday, 'Wednesday' : Wednesday, 'Thursday' : Thursday, 'Friday' : Friday, 'Saturday' : Saturday}
highestValue = max(weekdays, key=weekdays.get)
print("The highest rain total was " + highestValue + ' with ' + str(weekdays[highestValue]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sunday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Sunday: "))
Monday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Monday: "))
Tuesday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Tuesday: "))
Wednesday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Wednsday: "))
Thursday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Thursday: "))
Friday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Friday: "))
Saturday = float(input("Enter the rain totals for Saturday: "))

weekdays = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]

print("The highest rain total was Thursday with ", max(weekdays))

index = 0
```

You can change the text in the print statement to say anything you want.

Comment: @Endlessmitch I hope you can learn from this answer how to ask a better question.